# Is it possible to miss an event if you check its state and then add a listener?

Tags: javafx

Let's say I have a Worker that runs some background task. Is it possible for something like this to happen?

1. I check the `State` of the worker and it is still `State.RUNNING`.
2. I add a `ChangeListener` to the state property with a lambda to execute when it finishes `.stateProperty().addListener((o, v1, v2) -> doSomething())`
3. In between steps 1 and 2, in the background thread, the worker state changed to `State.SUCCEEDED`.

Now and the `ChangeListener` never fires and now I effectively end up waiting forever for the event to happen, because it has already happened and I missed it.

If this is possible, how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as this happens on the JavaFX application thread and registering the listener happens before you "return the control back to JavaFX" after checking the state (i.e. it happens in the same event handler, `Platform.runLater` runnable/change listener, ect.), you'll be notified of the change.

Here's the reason why: Changes to the `Task.state` property are done on the application thread which is the thread your code runs on. This means until you return the control to JavaFX, it cannot do an update to the property and after adding the listener the value contained in the property is still the same as the one you read.